# Getting error while fetching for graphql list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, fetch

I keep getting the same error when trying to fetch a list using graphql in an react application.

My following query:

```
const query = `{
  getConstructionNumberListing(filter: "{\"subProject__id\": \"36\"}") {
    edges {
      node {
        id,
        constructionNumber,
        indicativePrice,
        definitivePrice,
        isDefinitive,
        housingType {
          ... on object_HousingType {
            id,
            description
          }
        }
      }
    },
    totalCount
  }
}`

const url = constants.api.url;
  const body = JSON.stringify({
    query: query,
  })
 
  return new Promise((resolve) => {

    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers(),
      body: body
    })

      // Parse the response
      .then(res => res.json())

      // Trigger the callback if no errors were thrown
      .then(res => {
        console.log('res', res)
        resolve(res);
      })
      .catch(er => resolve(er))
  })
```

gives me this error while fetching in react:

```
{message: "Syntax Error: Expected :, found String \": \"", extensions: {category: "graphql"}, locations: [{line: 2, column: 57}]}
```

Who can help me solve this? other query like the following works fine

```
{
  getProjectListing(after: 0) {
      edges {
          node {
              id
              projectName
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Also want to mention that the query works fine in Postman, the syntax is from the docs:

https://github.com/pimcore/data-hub/blob/master/doc/10_GraphQL/04_Query/10_Filtering.md

Comment: 'Content-Type': 'application/json' .. also you should use 'query variables' to pass parameters (see docs), test in playground (using variables) then recreate in code, compare raw request details when in trouble

Answer (score 0):

You `filter` value is not a valid syntax, not sure what you trying to do but it might look like:

```
{
  getConstructionNumberListing(filter: "{ subProject__id: 36 }") {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your awnser. If i try that then i get the folllowing error: res
Object

data: Object

getConstructionNumberListing: null

Object prototype

errors: Array (1)
0 Object

extensions: {category: "pimcore.datahub"}

locations: [{line: 2, column: 3}] (1)

message: "unable to decode filter"

path: ["getConstructionNumberListing"] (1)

Object prototype

Comment: The syntax is from the docs: https://github.com/pimcore/data-hub/blob/master/doc/10_GraphQL/04_Query/10_Filtering.md

Answer (score -1):

You can use a library like apollo client to send graphql queries in react:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/

Comment: Thanks for your awnser but i would like to just use fetch. Should be possible